# Cartodb - How to insert geojson data to table using SQL api?

Tags: postgis, carto, geojson

I am currently using leaflet.js to generate polygons and I would like to add them to my table in cartodb. I.e. a geojson object :

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "wing1"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -60.1171875,
          54.16243396806781
        ],
        [
          5.9765625,
          70.0205873017406
        ],
        [
          41.484375,
          49.15296965617039
        ],
        [
          11.25,
          1.0546279422758869
        ],
        [
          -60.1171875,
          54.16243396806781
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
},
```

I am aware I can use the following api to insert new data to cartodb table.

```
https://{username}.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=INSERT INTO test_table (column_name, column_name_2, the_geom) VALUES ('this is a string', 11, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-110, 43),4326))&api_key={api_key}
```

But can someone explain to me how I can send a geojson object using the existing api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the CARTO SQL API, you can insert [your geojson sample](https://gist.github.com/ramiroaznar/4f5fd72ac77d012c211141077686b382) to a CARTO column value (`geojson_data`, for example). And then use [the PostGIS `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) and set `the_geom` to the result:

```
UPDATE 
  name_table
SET 
  the_geom = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson_data)
```

You will end up with [this dataset/map](https://team.carto.com/u/ramirocartodb/tables/geojson_table_geom/map).